# Could ImageIO be multi-threaded?

Tags: java, multithreading, javax.imageio

The [ImageIO Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/imageio/spec/goals.fm2.html) specifically states that thread-safety is a non-goal. `ImageIO.write`, in particular, looks like it might cache and reuse `ImageWriter` objects, and thus not be thread-safe.

Even if `ImageIO.write` were not thread-safe, would creating `ImageWriter` objects some other way (allocating new ones for each request, assuming that's possible) be thread-safe?

I had tried `synchronized` and `ThreadLocal`. Both could not work.

Comment: Why didn't `synchronized` or `ThreadLocal` work?

Comment: I glanced at the Guide.  It specifically says that multiple instances of the class must be able to operate simultaneously. So, if you have multiple requests, create multiple instances - that's how it's designed to work - each thread uses its own instance.

Answer (score 0):

This problem come from We can't create ImageWriter objects as much as we want, because it can't dispose or leak memories. So I decided to make a pool for ImageWriter.

I wrote very small class to manage ImageWriter pooling like following code.
*need to add error cases.

I used this pool with ExecutorService and Executors.newFixedThreadPool. It seemed to work.

```
public class PooledImageWriter {
static List<ImageWriter> mPool = new ArrayList<ImageWriter>();

public PooledImageWriter(String formatName, int size) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        mPool.add((ImageWriter)ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName(formatName).next());
    }
}

ImageWriter get() {
    if(mPool.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return mPool.remove(0);
}
void put(ImageWriter o) {
    mPool.add(o);
}

public void write(BufferedImage image, File file) throws Exception {
    ImageWriter writer = get();

    ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(file);
    writer.reset();
    writer.setOutput(ios);
    writer.write(image);
    ios.close();

    put(writer);
}
```

}

Comment: Ah, need to synchronize when get / put a ImageWriter from the pool.